# Modify CSS of the :after pseudo-element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I use the `:after` pseudo-element to display a decoration (triangle) after a block (`<li>` in my case). The idea is to distinguish the currently selected `li` from others.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/kbpg6/)

The html follows:

```
<ul>
    <li class="active" style="background-color: hsl(108, 60%, 50%)">One</li>
    <li style="background-color: hsl(36, 60%, 50%)">Two</li>
    <li style="background-color: hsl(252, 60%, 50%)">Three<li>
</ul>
```

and the css:

```
ul li {
    width: 300px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px dashed;
    position: relative;
}

li.active::after {
    content: " 0020";
    display: block;
    font-size: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    left:100%;
    top: 0%;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    background: transparent;
    border: 17px solid transparent;
    border-left-color: #FF3900;
}
```

I want to change the `border-left-color` style attribute of `li.active::after` pseudo element to match the `background-color` of the `<li>` element with `class=active`.

I came up with the following jquery:

```
$("ul li").click(function() {
    $("ul li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $("li.active::after").css('border-left-color', $(this).css('background-color'));
});
```

This doesn't work as expected. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if this is a copypasta/rewrite bug, but your `li.active::active` is missing `"` at the start and end.

Comment: JQuery cannot manipulate the `:after` pseudo element, as pseudo elements do not appear in the DOM

Comment: @BeatAlex Thanks for catching. It is a typo. However, that doesn't fix my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't select pseudo elements such as :before and :after with jquery. But in your case you can do a workaround to use the parent li's style on the :after and thus match the border-color property

[codepen](http://cdpn.io/DGFEv)

CSS updated:

```
ul li {
    width: 300px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px dashed;
    position: relative;
}
li:first-of-type.active {
  border-left-color: green; // your exact colors here
}
li:nth-of-type(2).active {
  border-left-color: orange;
}
li:last-of-type.active {
  border-left-color: purple;
}
li.active::after {
    content: " 0020";
    display: block;
    font-size: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    left:100%;
    top: 0%;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    background: transparent;
    border: 17px solid transparent;
    border-left-color: inherit;
}
```

and then just remove the line of js that includes the :after selector. not needed anymore

Comment: Very clever. I modified it a bit to get what I wanted here: http://jsfiddle.net/GR2w5/. Going to you :)

Answer (score 3):

I already wrote this as @DMTinter submitted his answer, so apologies for duplicate:

---

**Use The Border-Color Property Of Your Parent Element**

Because you can't select `:after` & `:before` pseudo elements in JQuery (I can't find a reference for this sorry), you'll have to play with the parent element's CSS to make it work:

http://jsfiddle.net/kbpg6/2/

As per your code:

```
<ul>
    <li class="active" style="background-color: hsl(108, 60%, 50%); border-color: hsl(108, 60%, 50%)">One</li>
    <li style="background-color: hsl(36, 60%, 50%); border-color: hsl(36, 60%, 50%)">Two</li>
    <li style="background-color: hsl(252, 60%, 50%); border-color: hsl(252, 60%, 50%)">Three<li>
</ul>

ul li {
    width: 300px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px dashed;
    position: relative;
    border-color: #ccc; /* -> default "arrow" colour */
}

li.active:after {
    content: " 0020";
    display: block;
    font-size: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    left:100%;
    top: 0%;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    background: transparent;
    border: 16px solid transparent;
    border-left-color: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I had to give it to @DMTintner as I saw his answer first. Thanks for your time though.

Comment: Np! I learnt something from it so no biggie